# BoundaryCallback Not Called With DataSource

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I created a boundary callback and a data source, the data source reads from the DB and the boundary callback is supposed to make the API calls and persist to the DB.

However, the overridden methods in boundary callback are never called, I don't know if there is a rule that says you can't mix both. But it is driving me crazy and I don't get it.

```
    private val postsDataFactory  = object: DataSource.Factory<String, Post>() {
        override fun create(): DataSource<String, Post> {
            return ItemDataSource(application)
        }
    }

    private val postsBoundaryCallback = object: PagedList.BoundaryCallback<Post>(){
        override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
            super.onZeroItemsLoaded()
            viewModelScope.launch {
                try {
                    val posts = postsRepo.findPosts(mutableMapOf("limit" to "1"))

                    database.postDao().create(posts)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.d("NETWORK_ERROR", e.message)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d("UNCAUGHT_ERROR", e.message)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: Post) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                try {
                    val posts = postsRepo.findPosts(mutableMapOf(
                        "before" to itemAtEnd.id,
                        "limit" to "1"
                    ))

                    database.postDao().create(posts)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.d("NETWORK_ERROR", e.message)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d("UNCAUGHT_ERROR", e.message)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private val postPageConfig = PagedList
        .Config
        .Builder()
        .setPageSize(10)
        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
        .build()

    val postsLiveData = LivePagedListBuilder(
            postsDataFactory,
            postPageConfig
        )
        .setBoundaryCallback(postsBoundaryCallback)
        .build()
```